Compact Casette Cover
Here a compact cassette cover:

Here the Code:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Gesamtcover (13 mm Titel + 65 mm Rückseite, zusammen 78 mm x 102 mm)
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Rahmen für Titelstreifen (13 mm x 102 mm)
        \draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (1.3,10.2); % 13 mm x 102 mm
        \node[align=center, font=\large, text width=8cm, rotate=90] at (0.65,5.1) {\textbf{Mixtape von Andreas S. "Der piekfeine Angler"}};

        % Rahmen für Rückseite (65 mm x 102 mm)
        \draw[thick] (1.3,0) rectangle (7.8,10.2); % 65 mm x 102 mm
        
        % Tracklist, leicht nach unten versetzt und gedreht
        \node[anchor=north west, font=\scriptsize, rotate=90] at (1.5,0.4) {
            \begin{minipage}{9.2cm}
                \begin{multicols}{2}
                    \raggedright
                    \textbf{Seite A} \\[0.4cm]
                    Earth Born - Kitaro \\
                    Bilitis Générique - Francis Lai \\
                    Et les oiseaux chantaient - Sweet People \\
                    Wolkenreise - Eroc \\
                    Flavio Let Me Be Like I Am - Pt. II - Carsten Bohn’s Bandstand \\
                    So Long Ago, So Clear - Jon \& Vangelis \\
                    If You Could Read My Mind - Johnny Cash \\
                    Suzanne - Leonard Cohen \\
                    Martha - Tom Waits \\
                    Zwanzig Meter Klingeldraht - Fortuna Ehrenfeld \\
                    Die Welt ist schön - Blumfeld \\
                    
                    \columnbreak
                    
                    \textbf{Seite B} \\[0.4cm]
                    Brothers In Arms - Dire Straits \\
                    The Man With The Child In His Eyes - Kate Bush \\
                    Your Love Is King - Sade \\
                    A Gentleman’s Excuse Me - Fish \\
                    Atmosphere - Joy Division \\
                    The Drugs Don’t Work - The Verve \\
                    Such Great Heights - Iron \& Wine \\
                    Letter In Icelandic From The Ninette San - John K. Samson \\
                    Tide - Wooden Arms \\
                    I Love My Harbour - Hundreds \\
                \end{multicols}
            \end{minipage}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}

Suggestions for further improvement?

What a vintage question! It's a shame there isn't a dedicated badge. :-)

What kind of improvements are you looking for? Is there something about the output you want to change? Or parts of the code that you find inefficient? Please make it specific. One thing though is that your opening quotes are not rotated, you can use \`Der piekfeine Angler'' ` for that, i.e., with double backticks as opening instead of double quotes.

Welcome. // Did you see these (old) packages? https://ctan.org/topic/covers

Not sure why you are rotating everything, nor why you loaded rotating (which isn't used).  If the goal is to pack several onto one page, you could use just landscape (either in the document class or with geometry).  (Does Avery make casette covers?)
